# How install PySide/PyQt in Blender?

Tags: add-on, external-applications

I want to create blender add-on using QT framework, but couldn't find any information about how install it in Blender.
I would be grateful for any information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either unpack the PySide/PyQt folder(s) to Blender's `site-packages`

```
\Blender\2.xx\python\lib\site-packages\>>HERE<<
```

You should then be able to `import` them normally.

Or install them to add them to your system's python installation and use `sys.path.append()` in your script to add the required folders to Blender's module search path temporarily and `import` as usual.